# Jersey2 Client: Use reserved characters without encoding

Tags: odata, jersey-2.0, url-encoding, jersey-client

I'm trying to call an OData service using Jersey2.

My problem is that

```
final WebTarget target = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://some.endpoint.url/odata/v1").path("MyEntity").queryParam("$top", 100);
```

is generated as

```
http://some.endpoint.url/odata/v1/MyEntity?%24top=100
```

instead of

```
http://some.endpoint.url/odata/v1/MyEntity?$top=100
```

How do I set a query parameter with a reserved character that must not be url encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly solution setting the problematic parts as URI to a new *WebTarget*:

```
final Client client = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient()
WebTarget target = client.target("http://some.endpoint.url/odata/v1").path("MyEntity");
target = client.target(target.getUriBuilder().uri(target.getUri() + "?$top=100"));
JsonNode response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).buildGet().invoke(JsonNode.class)
```

Better solutions are still preferred